# IF Else is failing me

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I keep getting my error that I have to enter both new passwords correctly in my code. Thats not what I want. IF the password field is filled out, then it should check for the password matches and fits the requirements. Otherwise, it should update the profile. But its not doing that. IT still checks for the password field. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong with my code?

```
    <?php
    if ($post == "yes") {


    $uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $password);
    $lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $password);
    $number    = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $password);

    if (isset($password) && ($password != $password2 || !$uppercase || !$lowercase ||    !$number || strlen($password) < 8)) {
    echo "<table class=tablenews><tr><td>There is an error with your passwords. Either they do not match, or your new password does not contain 8 characters, a number, a lower and an upper case letter. Go back and retry again. </td></tr></table>";

    }

    else {
     $password = generateHash($password);

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET avatar='" . $avatar . "' WHERE id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'") 
    or die(mysql_error());  
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_signature='" . $signature . "' WHERE id='".   $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_bio='" . $bio . "' WHERE id='".    $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_desc='" . $desc . "' WHERE id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_intro='" . $intro . "' WHERE id='".     $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='" . $password . "' WHERE id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
printf('<script>window.location = "http://www.sw-bfs.com/index.php?siteid=profileedit"</script>');
}

    if (!isset($password)) {
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET avatar='" . $avatar . "' WHERE id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'") 
or die(mysql_error());  
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_signature='" . $signature . "' WHERE id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_bio='" . $bio . "' WHERE id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_desc='" . $desc . "' WHERE id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_intro='" . $intro . "' WHERE id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 



    printf('<script>window.location = "http://www.sw-bfs.com/index.php?siteid=profileedit"</script>');

}


}

else {
?>

<table class="tablenews">
<tr><th>Edit your Profile</th></tr>

<?php
$userfinalid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$prAvatar = get_user_data($userfinalid, avatar);
$prSignature = get_user_data($userfinalid, signature);
$prBio = get_user_data($userfinalid, bio);
$prDesc = get_user_data($userfinalid, desc);
$prIntro = get_user_data($userfinalid, intro);
?>

<br><tr><td>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $thispage . "?siteid=profileedit"; ?>&proc=New&post=yes&<?php echo $pagevars; ?>">

<?php

echo '<label for="avatar" class=customlabelname>Avatar Link:</label><br><input type="text" class=customlabel name="avatar" value="' . $prAvatar .'"><br>';
echo '<label for="bio" class=customlabelname>User Bio:</label><br><textarea rows="10" cols="40" class=customlabel name="bio">' . $prBio .'</textarea><br>';
echo '<label for="desc" class=customlabelname>User Description:</label><br><textarea rows="10" cols="40" class=customlabel name="desc">' . $prDesc .'</textarea><br>';
echo '<label for="intro" class=customlabelname>User PM Intro:</label><br><textarea rows="10" cols="40" class=customlabel name="intro">' . $prIntro .'</textarea><br>';
echo '<label for="signature" class=customlabelname>User Signature:</label><br><textarea rows="10" cols="40" class=customlabel name="signature">' . $prSignature .'</textarea><br>';
echo '<label for="password" class=customlabelname>New Password(Leave Blank if it will be the same):</label><input type=password rows="10" cols="40" class=customlabel name="password"></textarea><br>';
echo '<label for="password2" class=customlabelname>ReType Password:</label><input type=password rows="10" cols="40" class=customlabel name="password2"></textarea><br>';
echo '<input type=submit value="submit" class=button2>';
?>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
    ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha the red box says it is deprecated in PHP5.5 (which is in alpha stage right now). You can't say it is deprecated, however it is not recommend anymore. And PDO or MySQLi doesn't mean prepared statements...

Comment: are you using register globals to set your variables????

Comment: You could use a single mysql update to update the fields rather than doing one for each field.

Comment: Yeah, I get confused when I do too many in one SQL update.

Comment: Are you sure `$password` has any data in it? Did you previously call `$password = $_POST["password"]` (or `$_GET["password"]` or `$_REQUEST["password"]`)? You would need to do that for all of your form data. And, by the way, this is an excellent way for someone to perform [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection), so beware!

Comment: I haven't added SQL Injection protection yet to this form. However, I am just trying to get it all set up right. For all the other data, if I remove the password stuff, it grabs it just fine without call $_POST, $_GET or $_REQUEST.

Comment: Then, perhaps `isset()` isn't doing what you expect. `isset()` will return true even if the variable is empty (declared, but empty). If you want to check if there is anything useful in $password, perhaps you could add a `strlen($password) > 0` check?

Answer (score 0):

```php
if (isset($_POST['password']) ...) {
    // ... display error
}
```

This means *if the `password` key does exist in the `$_POST` array, display the error*. I think you mean *if the `password` key **does not** exist in the `$_POST` array, display the error*. You should invert the if by putting a `!` before it:

```php
if (!isset(...) ...) {
```

Comment: Well, let me explain this better then: I am trying to create a profile page. A user can edit different things on there. If the password field is empty, it will update all the fields in the database, minus the pw field. If the password field is set, then it will check the minimum password requirements. If it matches, it will proceed to update the DB. If not, it gives the error message I set up. However, its not functioning like that. The first If isset, checks for the password field to be filled and then checks if it matches the requirements. If it doesn't, it elses to the next part. MakeSense?

Comment: I fixed the situation using `strlen($password) > 0` rather than isset or is null etc.. Do not know why it works that way and not the others, but it will work for now. Now I am off to fix the SQL Injection holes.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what are you wanting to do:

```
if(isset($password)) {
    if ($password != $password2 || !$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number || strlen($password) < 8) {
        error_log('error');
    echo "<table class=tablenews><tr><td>There is an error with your passwords. Either they do not match, or your new password does not contain 8 characters, a number, a lower and an upper case letter. Go back and retry again. </td></tr></table>";

    } else {
        $password = generateHash($password);

        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET avatar='" . $avatar . "' WHERE id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'")
        or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_signature='" . $signature . "' WHERE id='".   $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'")
         or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_bio='" . $bio . "' WHERE id='".    $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'")
        or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_desc='" . $desc . "' WHERE id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'")
        or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET u_intro='" . $intro . "' WHERE id='".     $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'")
        or die(mysql_error());
            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='" . $password . "' WHERE id='". $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'")
        or die(mysql_error());
        printf('<script>window.location = "http://www.sw-bfs.com/index.php?siteid=profileedit"</script>');
    }
}
```

Leaving the rest of your code the same and just replacing the first if/else.

Your code formatting could use some cleanup and you should really condense the mysql queries.

Comment: Is it possible the test data you are using legitimately fails the error checking? When I run it it seems to work as I think you intend.

Comment: I tested the data by echoing $password and if I live it blank, it doesn't show up, if I type something in, what I typed shows up. Yet, for some reason, the IF part of it is not behaving properly.

Comment: I fixed the situation using `strlen($password) > 0` rather than isset or is null etc.. Do not know why it works that way and not the others, but it will work for now. Now I am off to fix the SQL Injection holes.

Thanks everyone.